# Miniconda does not install correctly

Tags: python, conda, miniconda

I've made multiple attempts to install Miniconda on my Macbook running Catalina. I've been following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bbIG5d3bOmk) guide on YouTube about how to install it. The area where I run into issues is when the installation completes and I have to restart the terminal. According to the video, this should allow me to use the `conda` command in the terminal itself, thus allowing me to do what I need to do. The error message I receive is below:

> ERROR: The install method you used for conda--probably either `pip
>   install conda` or `easy_install conda`--is not compatible with using
>   conda as an application. If your intention is to install conda as a
>   standalone application, currently supported install methods include
>   the Anaconda installer and the miniconda installer.  You can download
>   the miniconda installer from https://conda.io/miniconda.html.

What confuses me most about this is the fact that I have done this exact step. This current installation is from the link they provided. Has anyone else run into any issues like this?

Comment: have you installed miniconda using `sudo` privileges?. It may be helpful to search your filesystem for the location of your conda installation files and update the question with this information. The error suggests a permission issue.

Comment: I doubt it's a permissions issue, and generally installing Conda with elevated privileges is strongly discouraged as it complicates management. My guess is it's a `zsh` vs `bash` issue. You have Catalina which means your default shell is now `zsh`, whereas the Miniconda install still might default to running `conda init bash`. Instead, locate the `conda` binary and run (something like): `/Users/you/miniconda3/bin/conda init zsh`.